# How to add style in html by htm.fromHtml() for java(android)

Tags: java, android, css, html

My html  page  below given---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
height: 100%;


}
h5{
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
height: 30px;
font-size: 27px;
background-position: center;
color:  Black;
padding: 75px;
background-size: contain;
}
 </style>
 <body>
    <h5>
    সমাপ্ত
    </h5>
 </body>
</html>
```

I  implemented this html  page by  this below  function in  android,But it's  only  display text,CSS is  not work!

```
      Spannable sequence = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml("<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n" +
                                "<html lang=\"en-US\">\n" +
                                "<head>\n" +
                                "\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
                                "\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n" +
                                "\t<title></title>\n" +
                                "</head>\n" +
                                "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                                "body{\n" +
                                "margin: 0;\n" +
                                "padding: 0;\n" +
                                "width:100%;\n" +
                                "height: 100%;\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "}\n" +
                                "h5{\n" +
                                "    text-align: center;\n" +
                                "    margin: auto;\n" +
                                "    position: absolute;\n" +
                                "    top: 0;\n" +
                                "    left: 0;\n" +
                                "    bottom: 0;\n" +
                                "    right: 0;\n" +
                                "    height: 30px;\n" +
                                "    font-size: 27px;\n" +
                                "    background-position: center;\n" +
                                "    color:  Black;\n" +
                                "    padding: 75px;\n" +
                                "    background-size: contain;\n" +
                                "}\n" +
                                "</style>\n" +
                                "<body>\n" +
                                "\t<h5>\n" +
                                "\t\tসমাপ্ত\n" +
                                "\t</h5>\n" +
                                "</body>\n" +
                                "</html>");
```

But  Only  html  text show ,CSS not  Work..what should  i do ? Any help is pleasure

Comment: use webview in place of textview

Comment: it is book reader  apps...this  page  only  show  when book  page  finished...thenn  how  can  i  add webview.pls help.  Prashant Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use all the `HTML` tags and attributes, please refer to [this](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) blog, that lists the all supported tags in `Html.fromHTML`

Comment: thanks bro.but can you please advise me how can i center a text of  device  screen.

Comment: @tanvir Simple you can use `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: if you are having textView then it should work, if not, try removing other HTML tags and just make a sample.